# ti is not defined while pulling xcom variable in S3ToRedshiftOperator

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am using **S3ToRedshiftOperator** to load csv file into Redshift database. Kindly help to pass xcom variable to S3ToRedshiftOperator. How can we push xcom without using custom function?

Error:

> NameError: name 'ti' is not defined

Using below code:

```
from airflow.operators.s3_to_redshift_operator import S3ToRedshiftOperator

def export_db_fn(**kwargs):
session = settings.Session()
outkey = S3_KEY.format(MWAA_ENV_NAME, name[6:])
print(outkey)
s3_client.put_object(Bucket=S3_BUCKET, Key=outkey, Body=f.getvalue())
ti.xcom_push(key='FILE_PATH', value=outkey)
return "OK"


with DAG(dag_id="export_info", schedule_interval=None, catchup=False, start_date=days_ago(1)) as dag:
export_info = PythonOperator(
    task_id="export_info",
    python_callable=export_db_fn,
    provide_context=True     
)


transfer_s3_to_redshift = S3ToRedshiftOperator(
        s3_bucket=S3_BUCKET,
        s3_key="{{ti.xcom_pull(key='FILE_PATH', task_ids='export_info')}}",
        schema="dw_stage",
        table=REDSHIFT_TABLE,
        copy_options=['csv',"IGNOREHEADER 1"],
        redshift_conn_id='redshift',
        autocommit=True,
        task_id='transfer_s3_to_redshift',
    )
            
    
start >> export_info >> transfer_s3_to_redshift >> end
```

Comment: This line `ti.xcom_push(key='FILE_PATH', value=outkey)` is causing the problem.

Comment: @user17558100 How? I want to push FILE_PATH value in redshift operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message tells the problem.
`ti` is not defined.

When you set `provide_context=True`, Airflow makes Context available for you in the python callable. One of the attributes is `ti` (see [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/138f38f6e0905c80a9f1a07a3d3ed3ffa0e0b0eb/airflow/utils/context.pyi#L83)). So you need to extract it from kwargs or set it in the function signature.

Your code should be:

```
def export_db_fn(**kwargs):
    ...
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    ti.xcom_push(key='FILE_PATH', value=outkey)
    ...
```

Or if you want to use `ti` directly then:

```
def export_db_fn(ti, **kwargs):
    ...
    ti.xcom_push(key='FILE_PATH', value=outkey)
    ...
```

Note: In Airflow >= 2.0 there is no need to set `provide_context=True`

Comment: What about pull operation? How can we define kwargs or ti into redshiftoperator
s3_key="{{kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(key='FILE_PATH', task_ids='export_db')}}",

Comment: You are mixing Jinja syntax with python syntax. for Jinja in templated fields there is no need for kwargs as there is no kwargs. `{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=your_task, key=your_key) }}` will work fine - assuming the parameter is templated.

Comment: Thanks a lot @elad

Comment: Can you please have a look at this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70599221/getting-error-while-doing-truncate-redshift-table-using-s3toredshiftoperator