# Getting error while doing truncate redshift table using S3ToRedshiftOperator

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-2.x

I want to truncate my Redshift table before loading CSV file into Redshift table.

**Error:**
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Invalid arguments were passed to S3ToRedshiftOperator (task_id: dag_run_s3_to_redshift). Invalid arguments were:
**kwargs: {'method': 'REPLACE'}

**Below Code:**

```
task_fail_s3_to_redshift =  S3ToRedshiftOperator(
        s3_bucket=S3_BUCKET,
        s3_key="{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='export_db',key='FILE_PATH_1')}}",
        schema="dw_stage",
        table="task_fail",
        copy_options=['csv',"IGNOREHEADER 1"],
        redshift_conn_id='redshift',
        method='REPLACE',
        task_id='task_fail_s3_to_redshift',
    ) 

 start >> task_fail_s3_to_redshift >> end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `method` parameter was added in [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/18027) it's available in:

```
apache-airflow-providers-amazon >= 2.4.0
```

The error you are having means that you are using older version of amazon provider which is why it doesn't work for you.

Your options are:

1.Upgrade the provider

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-amazon --upgrade
```

2.If upgrade is not an option then use the deprecated `truncate_table` parameter:

```
task_fail_s3_to_redshift =  S3ToRedshiftOperator(
        s3_bucket=S3_BUCKET,
        s3_key="{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='export_db',key='FILE_PATH_1')}}",
        schema="dw_stage",
        table="task_fail",
        copy_options=['csv',"IGNOREHEADER 1"],
        redshift_conn_id='redshift',
        truncate_table=True,
        task_id='task_fail_s3_to_redshift',
    )
```

Since you want truncate option - it will give you the same functionality.

Comment: How can we dump all records based on particular column of execution_date with value current_date( datatype as timestamp)  into redshift table. Currently it is dumping all data